# Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LinkedMap

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

getting error while executing the command:

```
hadoop jar /home/edureka/Desktop/firstnlast.jar FirstandLast hdfs:/FirstnLast/first-last_sample hdfs:/FirstnLastoutput
```

Code is as follows:

```
import java.io.IOException;
/*import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;*/

import org.apache.commons.collections4.map.LinkedMap;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class FirstandLast {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Path in=new Path(args[0]);
        FileSystem a=in.getFileSystem(conf);
        FileStatus s=a.getFileStatus(in);


        long len=s.getLen();

        if(len<=0){
            System.err.println("file size is empty");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        Job j = new Job(conf,"First and last lines");
        j.setJarByClass(FirstandLast.class);
        j.setMapperClass(Map1.class);
        j.setReducerClass(Red1.class);
        j.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
        j.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        j.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        j.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        Path outputPath = new Path(args[1]);

      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(j, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(j,outputPath);
        //deleting the output path automatically from hdfs so that we don't have delete it explicitly

        outputPath.getFileSystem(conf).delete(outputPath);

            //exiting the job only if the flag value becomes false

      System.exit(j.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);

    }

    public static class Map1 extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
        static int count=0;

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value , Context con) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
            count++;
            String line=value.toString();

                con.write(new IntWritable(1), new Text(count+"\t"+line));



        }
    }

public static class Red1 extends Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {

    @Override
    public  void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> value,
            Reducer<IntWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text>.Context con)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        LinkedMap<String,String> map=new LinkedMap<String, String>();
        String s="";
        for(Text a:value){
            s=a.toString();
            map.put(s, null);
        }
        String first[]=map.firstKey().split("\t");
        String last[]=map.lastKey().split("\t");
        con.write(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(last[0])),new Text(last[1]));
        con.write(new IntWritable(Integer.parseInt(first[0])),new Text(first[1]));


    }

    }

    }
```

Mapper class executing successfully but reducer is failing. It looks like error in linked map but unable to solve this. Could you please help out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program ran with out any error on my local machine, I got following output from 6 lines of file:

```
1   customer_id, server_id, code
6   11145456, 1436, 2
```

*Just copy `commons-collections4-4.1.jar` jar to `HADOOP_HOME/lib`: (for `hadoop-2.2.0` lib path is `$HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/lib/common`)*

```
[cloudera@quickstart lib]$ sudo cp /home/cloudera/Desktop/commons-collections4-4.1.jar /usr/lib/hadoop/.
[cloudera@quickstart lib]$ cd
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop jar Desktop/Strip.jar so.LinkedMapTest /user/cloudera/result.txt /user/cloudera/LinkedMapTest
....
16/07/24 10:20:33 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
16/07/24 10:20:40 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/07/24 10:20:49 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
```

*Run:*

```
hadoop jar /home/edureka/Desktop/firstnlast.jar FirstandLast hdfs:/FirstnLast/first-last_sample hdfs:/FirstnLastoutput
```

Comment: See updated answer: also add jar to `HADOOP_PATH` Are you using any IDE to create your jar?

Comment: I am using Eclipse.

Comment: what is /local/path/jar2.jar in updated answer in HADOOP_CLASSPATH?

Comment: Tht is for if you get any other class not found exceptions and you need to add more jars you can add separated by `:` - NOTE: `/local/path/to` you will need to edit as per location of jar in your environment

Comment: I just gave you an example of adding multiple jars in CLASSPATH

Comment: while executing the command(HADOOP Class path) it's saying invalid identifie.                                                                                           export HADOOP_CLASSPATH= $HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/home/edureka/Desktop/Case_studies/First_and_Last_lines/Jars/commons-collections4-4.1.jar                                              error:  bash: export: `:/home/edureka/Desktop/Case_studies/First_and_Last_lines/Jars/commons-collections4-4.1.jar': not a valid identifier

Comment: You have space after =, `export HADOOP_CLASSPATH= ` remove space after =

Comment: yeah I did it. exported the class path.But still hadoop job is failing.I thought that the issue with the linked map in Reducer. Is n't it? If I comment the reducer part code and ran it mapper is executing successfully.

Comment: just copy jar to `HADOOP_HOME/lib` - you should be fine - see updated answer

Comment: I did even that also, still problem persists.

Comment: Not sure, can we trouble shoot offline? I don't know if you will be ok to share you email here

Comment: yeah sure...  praveen.telugu88@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks a lot Ronak for your time and quick turn around.